# On a GPU in Linux, how can a process be killed when another process is launched, and then restarted when the other process completes?

Tags: linux, process, gpu, priority

I have a laptop that is normally running GPU cryptocurrency mining. I want the laptop to kill this cryptocurrency mining when any intensive deep learning process is launched. So, I'm not trying to lower the priority of the GPU cryptocurrency mining; I'm actually trying to kill the process when some obviously intensive GPU process (e.g. using TensorFlow) is launched.

How might this be done? Should I have a daemon running that watches for specific processes? It feels like this might be functionality already offered in Linux.

Comment: Have you tried to just `nice` the miner? That could be enough.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for the suggestion; I think `nice` is usable for CPU processes, when this is really a question of GPU usage. The CPU usage of the mining and the CPU usage of the deep learning both are minimal; the issue is that it needs to be one or the other using the GPU at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a systemd unit for launching and keeping alive a script that periodically checks for your machine learning process.

Place the following script in `/usr/local/bin` and make it executable with `chmod +x`

###### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#replace with your process names
plearning="tensorflow"
pmining="mining"

sleepint="30" #interval in seconds between checks

while true;
do
    if pgrep -x "$plearning" > /dev/null
    then
        killall -q "$pmining"
        logger "miner killed"

    fi
    sleep $sleepint
done
```

Create a systemd unit in `/etc/systemd/system`, for example `miningswitch.service`

###### Unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/miningswitch
ExecStop=killall miningswitch

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start and enable the service with `systemctl enable --now miningswitch.service`

Answer (score 3):

As the GPU relies on a CPU process and the hard disk for its data,
you could perhaps use `nice` together with
[ionice](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)
to reduce both the CPU and I/O priorities of the mining process.

Otherwise, you could create a `cron` task, running periodically,
to check for the presence of the deep learning process and kill the miner.

This task can be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep -x "deep-learning-process" > /dev/null
then
    kill "mining-process"
fi
```